# Replacing variables in a dictionaryand using doc.render

Tags: python, docx, editing

I am editing a template document using doc.render and replacing them with variables in my python code. However, if the variable is a number i dont want it to be rendered and instead replaced with ''. my question is how can i differentiate the context and doc.render to only replace certain variables.
currently i do it like this

```
doc = DocxTemplate('Template.docx')
            context = {
                'acc':acceleration,
                'dpt':depth
            }
doc.render(context)
```

So if acceleration is a number i want acc in the template to be '' and the rest to work as normal

Answer (score 1):

as I understand the docxtpl package, it works under the hood with the jinja2 package. So on option is to leverage the power of jinja2 and the offered `{% if users %}` conditions.

Never the less I would do most of the logic in python and only use the templates library to fill and render the template. Meaning, do the value transformation on the dictionary in python and then push this dict to the render method.

```
context = {'acc':acceleration,
           'dpt':depth}

# if the numeric values are given as strings
context_ = {k: v if not v.isnumeric() else "" for k,v in context.items()}
# if the numeric values are as numeric
context_ = {k: v if not any([isinstance(v, int), isinstance(v, float)]) else "" for k,v in context.items()}
doc.render(context_)
```